# Proof of $n\ge 6\implies 2n−8\le n^2−8n+ 16$ using induction.

Tags: logic, induction, solution-verification

> I have to do a proof by induction for this theorem:
>
> For each $n\in \mathbb N$ such that $n\ge 6$ we have $$2n−8\le n^2−8n+ 16$$

Is this possible, or should I do a different type of proof. I am confused how to prove that $1\in S$  when $n\ge 6$, so I am thinking maybe I need to first prove $6\in S$ and then handle $n>6 $?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Yes, use $n=6$ as your base case

Comment: Hint:  you may find it easier to rewrite your inequality as $0≤n^2-10n+24$.

Comment: note that it's easy to see that $(n-5)^2-1\ge0$ for $n\ge6$ without induction

Comment: Let S={n∈N|2n−8≤n^2−8n+ 16}.  Since, 2(6)−8 = 4 and (6)2−8(6) + 16 = 10, 4<10 , and 6∈S. Assume n∈S. Then, 2(n+ 1)−8 =2n−6 and (n+ 1)^2−8(n+ 1)−8 =n^2+ 2n+ 1−8n−8 + 8 =n^2−6n+ 1.Now, 2n−6< n^2−6n+ 1. Therefore, n+1 ∈ S. By PMI, S∈N.     So this is what I ended up saying, but I am not confident on the second assumption. Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Wont let me edit, but meant to say 4=4, not 10

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 4):

The answer given by Shaun is excellent and works in general but notice here that you can factor both sides of $$2n-8\le n^2-8n+16$$

$$2(n-4)\le (n-4)(n-4)$$

and since $$n\ge 6$$ you could simplify this inequality. Do you see how to proceed ?

Answer (score 2):

**Base case:** Let $n=6$. Then the LHS is $4$ whereas the RHS is $(6-4)(6-4)=4$, so $2n-8\le n^2-8n+16=(n-4)^2$ is true for $n=6$.

**Induction Hypothesis:** Assume that for some fixed $k\ge 6$ we have $$2k-8\le (k-4)^2.\tag{$I$}$$

**When $n=k+1$:** Suppose $n=k+1$. Then

$$\begin{align}
2(k+1)-8&=2k-6\\
&=(2k-8)+2 \\
&\le (k-4)^2+2\quad \text{(by }(I)\text{)}\\
&=k^2-8k+16+2\\
&=k^2-6k+9- (2k-9)\\
&\le k^2-6k+9\quad \text{(for }k\ge 6\text{)}\\
&=((k+1)-4)^2\\
&=(k+1)^2-8(k+1)+16,
\end{align}$$

which is the same as $(I)$ but with $k$ replaced by $k+1$, so if it's true for $k$, it is true for $k+1$.

**Conclusion:** By induction on $n$ for all integers $n\ge 6$, we have $$2n-8\le n^2-8n+16.$$